# What is a good free platform that allows code highliting/good code visualizations?

Tags: web, blogs

I want something similar to a Wordpress.com blog.

What site has a free solution like this?

I want to start a little WPF blog to help newbies with the same problems I've had in my learning of WPF.

Edit:
I need it to have a [code] tag or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress.com has support for source code presentation:
http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

If you aren't in to hosting your own blog, then WP is a very reasonable choice - ie, more than "Good Enough" to get started.